# Kmeans using DataFrame column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have something like that:

```
wines = spark.table("dane_nowe_csv")
selected = wines.select("price")
```

Price is a double.
The question is how can i convert this "selected" to valid type to use with that:

```
clusters = KMeans.train(selected, 2, maxIterations=10, initializationMode="random")
```

I'm trying to do that a lot of time today, I searched dozens of topics and there is always some errors and I have a feeling that there is some easy way to do this.

Comment: And with `DataFrames` use [`pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#k-means) not `pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeans`

Answer (score 0):

```
wines = spark.table("dane_nowe_csv")
selected = wines.select("price").map(s => s.getAs[Vector])
clusters = KMeans.train(selected, 2, maxIterations=10,initializationMode="random")
```

KMeans take rdd as input not dataframe or column.